Does the extra damage from an Aasimar's Celestial Revelation get applied on Graze?
For reference:

Mastery: Graze. If your attack roll with this weapon misses a creature, you can deal damage to that creature equal to the ability modifier you used to make the attack roll. This damage is the same type dealt by the weapon, and the damage can be increased only by increasing the ability modifier.

Celestial Relevation.

Once on each of your turns before the transformation ends, you can deal extra damage to one target when you deal damage to it with an attack or a spell.

So Graze damage cannot be increased by anything except the ability modifier. However, Celestial Revelation uses a wording of 'deals extra damage' and is worded in a way that might imply separate instance. What's everyone's take - does Celestial Revelation apply on a grazing hit when active, or not?

No is probably the intended ruling, but there's some ambiguity

However, Celestial Revelation uses a wording of 'deals extra damage' and is worded in a way that might imply separate instance.

That phrasing makes the damage part of the attack (or attack attempt if it applies to graze),
the key word being "extra".
It's basically the same phrasing as Sneak Attack ("you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack roll..."), and we all agree that Sneak Attack dice get doubled by a crit because it's part of the attack, not separate damage also triggered by the attack.
(Sneak Attack and Divine Smite definitely don't apply to Graze because they requires you to hit, so allowing Celestial Radiance wouldn't necessarily be opening the flood gates to other sources of extra damage.  But it would potentially allow barbarians to add rage bonus damage.)
Being part of the attack or not is also relevant for Grave Cleric's Path to the Grave (from XGE for dnd-2014): vulnerability to all of that attack's damage.  Unlike with crits that only affect dice, this affects flat bonuses, too.
This just leaves the question of whether "the damage can be increased only by ... is referring to just the weapon-damage part of the attack (e.g. a +1 magic weapon wouldn't add its bonus), or to the whole attack including any other damage bonuses (like rage) or sources of "extra" damage including of other types like this.
The wording is ambiguous as @nonymous points out, but the most likely intended meaning seems to me to exclude all sources of extra damage that would have been part of the attack if it had hit.
If there are any abilities that let you do damage when you damage a creature without using the word "extra" or "bonus", then those could be triggered by Graze.

Sneak attack is part of an attack, but it's still extra damage, not simply an increase in the attack damage. I think the crit line of thought is misleading, although I agree with the conclusion, I think.

@SeriousBri: My point with that was to respond to the OP's "separate instance" suggestion and narrow the question down to what exactly the Graze phrasing means: can't increase the total damage of the attempted attack in other ways, or can't increase the graze damage proper e.g. with more direct bonuses like magic weapons.  That's still ambiguous, and the fact that the damage would be part of the attack doesn't let us sidestep that debate / ambiguity.

No
Graze damage can only be increased by increasing your ability modifier. Thus Celestial Revelation cannot increase its damage.
I do agree that there is some ambiguity here, but the wording of Celestial Revelation isn't too different from other riders, i.e. the barbarian's Rage Damage which notably does not require you to hit the target (unlike the Rogue's Sneak Attack), just that you deal damage. I'm fairly confident that Graze's damage increase restriction is there explicitly to disallow attack damage riders - regardless of their wording.

If that is the purpose of the restriction then it doesn't do a very good job. Things like celestial revelation deal additional damage, they don't increase damage. Maybe (probably) it's the intention but absolutely not raw. I don't even think it's slightly ambiguous the way it is worded, the only ambiguity is because you think it is intended to mean something other than what it says.

@SeriousBri I am actually inclined to agree.

Is it acceptable to change a no answer to a yes answer, considering that those who voted for the answer might not agree with it after editing?

Not really, but it is fine to make 2 answers or to delete this one and make another.

Probably not, but maybe
There are two considerations, 1) whether Graze is attack damage and 2) whether the clause

the damage can be increased only by increasing the ability modifier...

pertains only to the weapon damage, or also to and applied damage.
Firstly, it depends on whether or not Graze's damage in part of an attack. Technically, the damage is an externality  of missing an attack; it's not an attack itself, properly. So, you might argue that it's ineligible on those grounds alone. On the other hand, Graze damage is necessarily part of an attack, both technically and narratively. It would be odd to abstract it away from the attack in any kind of applied context. As a rule of thumb, if you make an attack and deal damage, it should probably count as attack damage. Therefore, it probably should be eligible under Celestial Revelation's

...deal damage to it with an attack...

But, it would be perfectly reasonable for a GM to say otherwise.
Secondly, it depends on whether Graze's

the damage can be increased only by ...

strictly refers to the Graze weapon's attack damage, or to any damage resulting from the Graze property. Certainly, it's reasonable to assume that the damage refers only to the weapon damage. If this were the case, Celestial Revelation's necrotic/radiant damage would be strictly adding different damage, rather than increasing the pertinent damage; so, it could be applied on top of the Graze damage. But, since Graze's damage is unblockable, it would probably be more reasonable for a GM to assume the opposite, that the damage refers to any and all damage resulting from Grazes. So, even thought it's probably eligible, it also probably explicitly restricted.
